# Extending a list of list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

Is there anyway that I can extend a list of list in Haskell?

I'm trying to write a function that generates [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4.....] which is basically a 1 one, 2 twos, 3 threes etc.

My Attempt:

> ```
> nnss :: [Integer]
> nnss = [nPrint x x | x <- [1,2..]]
> ```

The problem with my attempt is that `nPrint x x` returns a list of integers, for example, nPrint 2 2 would return [2, 2]. Is there anyway I can "expand" the list from [1,2,3...] to [1,2,2,3,3,3...] ?

Comment: `nPrint` is a bad name for this (printing is an IO action), what you use is basically just `replicate`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function signature we're looking for is `[[a]] -> [a]` and if we check [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5Ba%5D%5D-%3E%5Ba%5D) we see that `concat` is what we're looking for.

And in this case though, the list comprehension is unnecessary since we're just iterating over each item, so we really want to just do a `map`. So since combining `map` and `concat` is so common we can just write

```
concatMap (\x -> nPrint x x) [1..]
```

You can ignore this if you're new to haskell but since the list monad is defined with `concatMap` we could also write

```
[1..] >>= \x -> nPrint x x
```

Comment: And if we really wanna play Haskell golf we could do `[1..] >>= join replicate`, using `replicate` as leftaroundabout suggests above and the `join` function from `Control.Monad` (in this case for the `((->) r)` monad instance, with type `(r -> r -> a) -> r -> a`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also write it without using maps and list concatenations (just prepend in constant time):

```
nnss :: [Integer]
nnss = genRepeated 1 1

genRepeated :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
genRepeated x 0 = genRepeated (x+1) (x+1)
genRepeated x y = x : genRepeated x (y-1)
```

Than

```
take 22 nnss == [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7]
```

---

Other fast possibility is:

```
nnss :: [Integer]
nnss = flatten [take x $ repeat x | x <- [1..]]

flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten [] = []
flatten ([]:xs) = flatten xs
flatten ((x:xs):ys) = x : flatten (xs:ys)
```

Comment: These are both slower than what I have above when I profile it

Comment: @jozefg Oh, is it assymptotically or constant times slower? Do you know why is that? I didn't meant it as faster, just more beginner friendly, but I am interested in what caused the difference.

Comment: FYI your custom function `flatten` is just `concat`: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:concat

Answer (score 0):

Just add `concat`:

```
nnss :: [Integer]
nnss = concat [nPrint x x | x <- [1,2..]]
```